# Keep uppercase using attr() with jquery (case sensitive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am doing this with jQuery :

```
@xmlOut = $('<rules />')
@xmlOut.attr('xsi:schemaLocation','test')
```

I get this :

```
<rules xsi:schemalocation='test'></rules>
```

The "L" is not uppercase anymore...

Answer (score 10):

There is a ticket http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11166

Alternatively, you can add attribute hook (with lowercase name) to jQuery in order to use desired setter method. For example:

```
$.attrHooks['viewbox'] = {
    set: function(elem, value, name) {
        elem.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', value + '');
        return value;
    }
};
```

Then you can set the attribute case sensitive with .attr():

```
$('svg').attr('viewBox', '0 0 100 100');
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using plain Javascript's `setAttribute` which is not case sensitive.

```
@xmlOut.get(0).setAttribute('xsi:schemLocation', 'test');
```

Comment: I thought `setAttribute` lowercases attribute names. I'm pretty sure I've seen that behaviour before.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Good question by the way.

Comment: Example : test = $('<div />'); test.get(0).setAttribute('TEST','lala')  => <div test=​"lala">​</div>​

Comment: This is incorrect according to the spec:

"The attribute name is automatically converted to all lower-case when setAttribute() is called on an HTML element in an HTML document."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 3):

Kevin's answer is incorrect, .setAttribute() will change the attribute name to lowercase.

Instead, use element.setAttributeNS() with an empty string for the first parameter.

```
@xmlOut.get(0).setAttributeNS('', 'xsi:schemaLocation','test')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS

Comment: Thank you so much for this, you should be on top. Actually, this is the only cross-browser solution! To add XML styles to my DataTables.net Excel export project, I had to switch from **.innerHTML** and **.insertAdjacentHTML** (both not recognized in Internet Explorer 11) to **elt = document.createElement("numFmt")** + **elt.setAttribute("formatCode", "0")** (lowercased in Chrome and Firefox) + **numFmts.appendChild(elt)**, to eventually **elt .setAttributeNS("", "formatCode", "0")** !

Comment: Precision: as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/26996439/5426777, you need to use **.createElementNS()** along with **.setAttributeNS()**

Comment: Also see my complete answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719888/5426777. 

Hope it will help you!