# Create XML DOM Element while keeping case sensitivity

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I'm trying to create the following element nodetree:

```
<v:custProps>
    <v:cp v:nameU="Cost">
</v:custProps>
```

with:

```
newCustprop = document.createElement("v:custProps");
newcp = document.createElement("v:cp");
newcp.setAttribute("v:nameU", "Cost");
newCustprop.appendChild(newcp);
```

However, `document.createElement("v:custProps")` generates `<v:custprops>` as opposed to `<v:custProps>`. Is there anyway to escape this parsing?

---

**Edit 1:**

I'm currently reading [**this**](http://ejohn.org/blog/nodename-case-sensitivity/) article on nodename case sensitivity. It's slightly irrelevant to my problem though because my code is unparsed with `<![CDATA]]>` and I'd rather not use `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `createElementNS()`/`setAttributeNS()` and provide the namespace, not only the alias/prefix. The example uses `urn:v` as namespace.

```
var xmlns_v = "urn:v";
var newCustprop = document.createElementNS(xmlns_v, "v:custProps");
var newcp = document.createElementNS(xmlns_v, "v:cp");
newcp.setAttributeNS(xmlns_v, "v:nameU", "Cost");
newCustprop.appendChild(newcp);

var xml = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(newCustprop);
```

xml:

```
<v:custProps xmlns:v="urn:v"><v:cp v:nameU="Cost"/></v:custProps>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended to use `document.createElement` for qualified names. See if the [`document.createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElementNS) can better serve your purposes.

Comment: `.createElementNS` lacks the namespace for XML elements it seems .. I've tested it and the Javascript generated returns an case insensitive result.

Answer (score 1):

I still had issues where createElementNs would attach an attribute of "xmls" on my string about using `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc)`.

I ended up using the following function to create elements with case sensitive tag names:

```
function createElement(tagName) {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<${tagName}></${tagName}>`, 'text/xml')
  return doc.children[0]
}
```