# How to add rows shifting rest of content in ExcelHtml5 datatables

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

Is there a way to add rows shifting rest of content in ExcelHtml5 datatables?
I need to insert a row between 'New York' and 'Chicago'

This is my scenario:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxYE7.png)

and this how i'd like to be:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3bun.png)

this is my script:

```
var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
var downrows = 1;
var clRow = $('row', sheet);
var msg;
//update Row
clRow.each(function(x) {
var attr = $(this).attr('r');
var ind = parseInt(attr);
    if (attr>3) {ind = ind + downrows; }
        $(this).attr("r", ind);});    
// Update  row > c
$('row c ', sheet).each(function(y) {
var attr = $(this).attr('r'); 
var pre = attr.substring(0, 1);
var ind = parseInt(attr.substring(1, attr.length));

if (y>10) {ind = ind + downrows; }
     $(this).attr("r", pre + ind);});
```

***** UPDATES!!!!
finally I managed to add a row in the middle of other rows but now I can't write in that created row.

Here my Jsbin -->    https://jsbin.com/menujozine/1/edit?html,output

PLEASE HELP ME!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear (to me, at least) what exactly you are asking, here. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you edit your question?

Comment: I need to insert a row...between the second and the third row in my excel jquery datatables Export. I know it’s the possibility to insert rows before the table like this thread....but I need between the rows:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485310/exporting-jquery-datatable-to-excel-with-additional-rows-is-not-working-ie?r=SearchResults

Comment: Please edit your question, instead of using comments, to clarify your request. Show us the code you have written, so we know what you have already tried. Show us what worked, and what did not work. Show us a sample of the data you are trying to manipulate. Show us what you expect/need, as the outcome. Taking these steps will make it more likely that you will get the answer you need. Thank you!

Comment: Ok just done...

Comment: nobody may help me???